# Unable to use Bokeh and Panda to read a csv and plot it

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to plot a line graph from a simple CSV file with two columns using Bokeh for data visualisation and Panda to read the CSV and handle the data. However, i can't seem to pass the data I've imported using pandas to Bokeh to plot my line graph.

This is running locally on my computer. I've tried and debugged each section of the code and the sole problem seems to occur when I pass the data from pandas to bokeh.

I've tried printing the columns I've selected from my csv to check that the entire column has been selected too.

```
#Requirements for App
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

#Import data-->Weight measurements over a period of time [ STUB ]
weight = pd.read_csv("weight.csv")

#Define parameters
x=weight["Date"]
y=weight["Weight"]

#Take data  and present in a graph
output_file("test.html")
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
p.line(x,y,line_width=2)
show(p)
```

I expect to get a line graph that plots each weight entry each day but I get a blank plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. Pandas doesn't know that it is working with dates so you have to specify this with pd.to_datetime().

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import DatetimeTickFormatter, ColumnDataSource

#Import data-->Weight measurements over a period of time [ STUB ]
weight = pd.read_csv("weight.csv")

#Define parameters
weight["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(weight['Date'])
weight["Weight"] = pd.to_numeric(weight['Weight'])

source = ColumnDataSource(weight)

#Take data  and present in a graph
output_file("test.html")
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, x_axis_type='datetime')
p.line(x='Date',y='Weight',line_width=2, source=source)
p.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter(
    minutes=["%M"],
    hours=["%H:%M"],
    days=["%d/%m/%Y"],
    months=["%m/%Y"],
    years=["%Y"]
)
show(p)
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Jasper ! This helped me to get the graph I wanted. Just curious, Why do you convert the imported csv to a ColumnDataSource. Is this necessary and if so, what purpose does it serve?

Comment: It's not necessary to use a ColumnDataSource in this case, it's used to do more advanced visualizations with Bokeh (Display data on hover, streaming data, etc...). I saw that you already imported it so I thought it would be nice to also show how you should use it.

Comment: I see! Thanks so much Jasper :)

Comment: @Jasper thank you so much. This is old but it has saved me in 2021 :)

Comment: @Grantx Glad to hear :)